# Why does &str::from(...) not create a String?

Tags: rust, traits

From the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html): `From<T> for U` implies `Into<U> for T`. Everyone uses `let x = String::from(z);` meaning we have `From<&str> for String` and thus we should have `Into<String> for &str`.

However, the following does not work:

```
fn main() {
    let z = "abc";
    let x = String::from(z);
    let s = &str::into(z);
}
```

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Note that the existence of `String::from` does not imply that `String` implements the trait `From`.

Comment: Do you mean `let s = &str::into(z);`?

Comment: Why do you believe "everyone is using `String::from()`"? I for one use `.to_owned()`, and I know plenty that use `.to_string()` or `.into()` (but `<&str>::into()` is rather uncommon, because _why_ when you can use method syntax instead?)

Comment: @jthulhu Well, I'd say it would be unusual if it wouldn't.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman my point is that, as the OP may not know, implementing a trait does not work like interfaces (or duck typing) might work in other languages, where having the same methods as required in a trait is enough to implement the trait. My point was not that types that have a `from` associated function do not usually do so because they implement the `From` trait.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works, except that `&str::into(z)` is understood as `&(str::into(z))`. If you want to call the associated function `into` for type `&str`, you must use a qualified name for that type:

```rust
fn main() {
    let z = "abc";
    let x = String::from(z);
    let s: String = <&str>::into(z);
}
```

Note that the type annotation `String` was added because otherwise Rust cannot know which type is the target of `into`.

Otherwise, you can also use the method syntax

```rust
    let s: String = z.into();
```

or the associated function of trait `Into`:

```rust
    let s: String = Into::into(z);
```

Comment: Why is &str::into(z) understood as &(str::into(z)) ?

Comment: @Brett Its just the way [operator precedence](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#expression-precedence) was designed. From the reference, paths (i.e. `::`) has a higher precedence than unary operators (i.e. `&`). That and you can only use `::` with identifiers (which `&str` is not, but `str` is) unless you do `<...>::`.

Comment: @Brett additionally, `&` cannot be a part of a path. If you need to name a type that involves something other than an identifier, you need to wrap it with `<` and `>`.

Comment: @jthulhu your main() does not compile.

Comment: @Brett Looks like a simple typo (they used `x` where they should've used `z`). I've corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

You got turned around there a bit. Happens to me a lot with the whole to and from ;)

Let's consider the types. `x` is `String`. So `into(x)` would attempt to turn a `String` into a `&str`, and you can't do that like this.

The fact that `String` implements `From<&str>` means that `&str` implements `Into<String>`, i.e., you can turn a `&str` into a `String`.

Here's what you really want:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x: &str = "abc";
    let z: String = String::from(x);
    
    let s: String = x.into();
}
```

No problem there!